# Angularjs - 500 (Internal Server Error) on $http Post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, gulp

I am new to Ionic and angular. I am building a sample with ionic framework using angular.js. I want to call WebApi through $http post method. I checked this([ionic-proxy-example](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-proxy-example)) solution and I am trying to implement the same using my api. When I call the api provided in above example in my sample project, I get the records but its not working with my api. It throws 500 internal error.

Here is my app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services'])
.constant('ApiEndpoint', {url: 'http://localhost:8100/api'})
```

Services.js

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.factory('Api', function($http, $q, ApiEndpoint) {


console.log('ApiEndpoint', ApiEndpoint)

 var getApiData = function() {
var q = $q.defer();

        var data = {
            Gameweek_ID: '179',
            Vender_ID: '1',
            Language:'en'
        };

         var config = {
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset = utf-8;"
            }
        };

        $http.post(ApiEndpoint.url, data, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           // $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
              alert('success');
              console.debug("response :" + data);
              q.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            // $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
              alert('error');
              console.debug("error :" + data);
              q.reject(data);
        });


return q.promise;


 }

 return {getApiData: getApiData};
})
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, Api) {
 $scope.employees = null;
Api.getApiData()
.then(function(result) 
{console.log("result is here");
jsonresponse = result.data;
$scope.employees = jsonresponse;}
)
```

});

And Ionic.Project File

```
{


"name": "Multilingual",
"app_id": "4b076e44",
"proxies": [
{
  "path": "/api",
  "proxyUrl": ""
}
]}
```

I am trying to understand the problem and checked multiple methods to call the api. Surprisingly, it works with ajax post call without any CORS errors. As I am using Angular, I am trying to get this done through $http post. I feel it is some minor issue but I am not able to figure out. Will be grateful for solutions. Thank you.

Comment: where do you get the error in the front end app or in the backend ? also check in developer console/ networks on what your request looks like and double check the url you are sending

Comment: The error is on the browser, when browser makes the request to api. I get the result when I ping on Fiddler.

Comment: what do you get in the backend side ? is your backend expecting any xcrf token ?

Comment: I encountered cross origin resource sharing(CORS) error on mozilla and chrome when I did simple $http post without setting up proxy. Then, I checked this post http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/ to set up proxy on client side inorder to bypass CORS which I was able to do in demo provided in the link.

Answer (score 2):

You've set the content type to json so the sever is expecting a json string but isn't receiving a properly formatted json string as you're sending through an object and hence the error.

Where you have `$http.post(ApiEndpoint.url, data, config)` change it to `$http.post(ApiEndpoint.url, JSON.stringify(data), config)`.

If that doesn't work, change your content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and update this line `$http.post(ApiEndpoint.url, data, config)` to `$http.post(ApiEndpoint.url, $httpParamSerializer(data), config)` , don't forget to inject the `$httpParamSerializer` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending a POST with `$http.post` request instead of a GET request with `$http.get`

Comment: The api is configured to receive POST requests. I am sending "data" explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below-

```
$http({
            url: ApiEndpoint.url,
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).Success(..rest code goes here..)
```

In WebAPI, when we pass more than one object in POST method, we get 500 internal error and hence we use ViewModel in such scenarios(talking about asp.net MVC).